# Weird HTML formatting with prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier-vscode

I have [this HTML](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xMmW7DkcFd/) when I use the built-in formatter. Not good. I want every tag to be cascaded. Here, we have span and svg and a on same line.

[image]

After formatting with prettier ([this version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode))

I get this. This is almost worse. *(see edit section later that explains why it’s actually a smart choice from prettier.)*

[image]

Prettier config is

[image]

What can I use to properly auto format this HTML ?

---

**Edit**: I got what I want with the [Beautify extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) and editing its inline config.
[image]

[Here](https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting) is why prettier is formatting like this. It is a workaround to not break  content display. Actually, it is pretty smart once you get used to it.

You can override it with the option

```json
"prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
```

See the link above to know more about this.

Comment: Please add the code instead of screenshots if possible.

Comment: @srishtigarg
The code is the first link at the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a prettier format as the default format for your editor to all programming languages by putting prettier properties in the `setting.json` file.

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
```

Prettier format for HTML doesn't look so cool in my opinion so I have set it to default VS Code format.

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
```

If you want the Beautify format extension to your HTML you can install the beautify extension and add this line in the `setting.json` file

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
}
```

Similarly, you can set a different format extension to a different language. In my opinion, this is the standard way of setting the format extension to one or many languages.

You can do it like this

```
"beautify.language": {
    "html": ["html", "php", "erb"],
},
```

**Edited**

All credits to @Fred.

You can achieve the same behavior of beautify extension in prettier by the following property.

```
"prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"
```

Comment: I know. I updated my question to add why prettier html formatting is in this way.

Comment: Maybe this [blog](https://css-tricks.com/prettier-beautify/) will help you. In my opinion, beautify is good for HTML and prettier is good for JSX. If someone knows the reason then this issue would have been solved before and updated in prettier extension. Maybe in the future, it would be solved.

Comment: In fact, there is no issue with prettier. It’s an option. This one 
 "prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore". Now it will format as Beautify does.

Comment: oh, Thanks buddy One more question why are you setting prettier properties as it does formatting of code? Does that mean you are customizing the prettier properties?

Comment: It does much better than beautify.

Comment: `"prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"` worked great for me. Thanks @FredEric :)